# save mysql result in an array PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this sql table

```
username | coins| id | date
test     | 1    | 5  | 05-26-2020
test     | 1    | 4  | 05-26-2020
test     | 1    | 2  | 05-26-2020
test     | 1    | 5  | 05-26-2020
test     | 1    | 7  | 05-26-2020
test     | 1    | 5  | 05-26-2020
test     | 1    | 1  | 05-26-2020
```

and I have to do SELECT  `username` 
FROM  `coins_logs` 
WHERE  `id` =5
and save the results in an array, so I'll can do `echo $results[4]` and print the 4th username

but how can I do it?

**update**

this is my code:

```
$idprodotto = '5';

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username FROM coins_logs WHERE   id= '$idprodotto';");

$utentiUltimi = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

echo $utentiUltimi[1];
echo $utentiUltimi[0];
echo $utentiUltimi[3];
```

I've tried to do `print_r($utentiUltimi)` and this is the result: Array( [0] => test )  so I think that don't take all the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array` will only return the next result row or `NULL` if there is no more row.

So, you have to read it in a loop to get all usernames:

```
$usernames= array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {
  $usernames[] = $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fetchAll() with PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

or [mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

/* numeric array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Comment: I've tried to do `$results = mysqli_fetch_array($query)` and `echo $results[1]; echo $results[2]; echo $results[4];` but it print only one username

Comment: try with this mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_NUM);

Comment: doesn't work, I've tried to do `print_r($utentiUltimi)` and this is the result: Array( [0] => test )  so I think that don't take all the data

Comment: Do you have all the results on $query ?

Comment: I don't know, how can I see it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way.

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

## output

```
Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => apple
            [0] => apple
            [colour] => red
            [1] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => pear
            [0] => pear
            [colour] => green
            [1] => green
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => watermelon
            [0] => watermelon
            [colour] => pink
            [1] => pink
        )

)
```